# Generating .jar using Java 1.7 with Eclipse and SQL Server 2012 database with Windows authentication

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Java 1.7 Desktop application with Eclipse and SQL Server 2012 database with Windows authentication. When I run through eclipse works correctly. The problem is when I try to generate a .Jar. The application works correctly but when I am going to do some query on the database the application stop working. I wonder what are the correct settings I have to do on the machine (the same machine) and time to generate. Jar, thanks.

Got this error by compiling in the prompt:

```
C:\Users\jean>java -jar C:\Users\jean\Desktop\Jean\aee.jar
Jan 15, 2014 8:29:34 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
AdvertÛncia: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java
.library.path
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Esse driver nÒo estß configurad
o para autenticaþÒo integrada. ClientConnectionId:02155bdf-555d-4b59-8933-a98091
48a83f
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerC
onnection.java:1667)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>
```

---

My problem is solved by just adding the .dll in the same directory of the .jar.

Comment: Please send us more information.  Do you have a stack trace of the error you get when you try to run the stand-alone jar application?

Comment: Thanks, I got the error which is in the question now.

Comment: It looks like you need some `sqljdbc_auth.dll` (native dynamic library) in your application path.  Does not it come with your jdbc driver?

Comment: Found some official documentation for your problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1c1a1313-057d-46d4-9ca7-82fc4f23a150/cant-get-integratedsecurity-with-jdbc-driver?forum=sqldataaccess http://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms378428.aspx

Comment: Actually yes, I put it in the VM Arguments at Eclipse, worked properly. But with the .jar application I've got this error.

Comment: Then, you must figure a way to make more portable that configuration detail and make it easier to deploy.  For example, you can make a bundle with your .jar, every library you need and a .bat startup script with the necessary jvm arguments (classpath, java.library.path, etc.)

Comment: Actually I solved by just adding the .dll in the same directory of the .jar. Thank you very much for your assistance, @Jorge_B. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you use some libraries for your project. If you export a jar from Eclipse, it doesn't package those libraries into that jar automatically. As an easy way out you coul'd use the [Fat Jar Plugin](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/). It worked fine for me in the past.

Ultimately you want to use a build and dependency management tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).